# Windows phone 8.1 ComboBox style Image

Tags: c#, templates, combobox, windows-phone-8.1, styles

I want to include an image directly into a ComboBox template.

I found this part of the code and I believe it is here where I would put it:

```
<Button x:Name="FlyoutButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" FontWeight="Normal" FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}" FontSize="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" MinHeight="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemMinHeightThemeSize}" Padding="6.5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
   <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Margin="0,0.8,0,0" MinHeight="32.5">
       <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxPlaceholderTextBlockStyle}" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"/>
   </ContentPresenter>
</Button>
```

I can't put an Image inside contentPresenter because it says I can only set 'Content' once.

If I make something like:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Margin="0,0.8,0,0" MinHeight="32.5">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxPlaceholderTextBlockStyle}" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"/>
       <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Arrow.png" />
   </StackPanel>
</ContentPresenter>
```

It actually works but I get an error in my XAML view page: "No installed components were detected. Cannot resolve TargetName PlaceholderTextlock.". And also the image disappears after I select an item.

I'd appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to set the items inside the combo box to have the image with the textblock. In that case you need to set the ItemTemplate of the combobox like this

```
<ComboBox Name="hik" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource cmbx}">
```

And in your page resources you can define the item template for combo box items like this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="cmbx">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Aqua">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Foreground="Black"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Some Text" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Image Source="/Assets/1.png" Stretch="Uniform" Height="100" Width="100" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Once that is done when you run it on clicking the combobox you can see the list with image

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but it helped me a bit. I got what I wanted eventually. Thank you.

Comment: I did but: "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score." - Stackoverflow